# MySQL installer did not installed MySQL Server in Windows 7, 32bit

Tags: mysql

I have completed the installation of MySQL installer though, it did not installed MySQL Server. The option I choose is the Developer Default. I have the MySql Server option in the MySql installer set-up type wizard as in this image. [MySQL server option present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkalC.png)

But, in the next step of the installation wizard I do not see MySql server in the list of products to be installed. Refer this image. 
[MySQL Server Option absent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gStVZ.png)

After the completion of the setup, I do not get the MySQL Server installed in my pc. What did I have to do to get MySQL Server installed in my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except I was on Windows Vista. Tried to install MySql version 8, then 5.7, but couldn't both times. Finally, 5.6 worked. So it's likely you just need an earlier version.

Comment: Is the second one was 32 bit too?

Comment: Yes, tried to install to my laptop which is also 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think all mysql server versions after 5.7 could not be installed on 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with full option but not "Developer Default"